# Anchor tag scroll animation using images with a tags

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, anchor

The code below animates my same-page anchor links `<a href="#contact">Contact</a>`, but the animation doesn't work if I combine it with an image `<a href="#to-top"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>`. With an image, a click will take you to the destination, but without the animation.

The destinations have a format like this: `<div id="contact">...</div>`.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
$('a').click(function(){ // I tried changing the 'a' to 'img', to no avail...
    var topoffset = 68;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top-topoffset+2
    }, 800);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> but the animation doesn't work if I combine it with an image . With an image, a click
>   will take you to the destination, but without the animation.

Appear to perform animation effect at stacksnippets ?

```js
$('a').click(function(){ // I tried changing the 'a' to 'img', to no avail...
    var topoffset = 68;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top-topoffset+2
    }, 800);
    return false;
});
```

```css
#contact {
  position:relative;
  top:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a title="click" href="#contact"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/technics/" /></a>
<div id="contact">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I moved my scripts to the bottom of the page, and the problem resolved itself.